# function return as object value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return some text from a function within an object. This text should then be used as the value. But its setting the whole function as the text.
Not sure what to do about it. e.g:

```
form_fields = [];    
form_fields.push({
  value: function () {
          return "test123"
  },
  name:name,
  type:$(this_el).attr('type')
});

console.log(form_fields[0].value);
```

results in:

```
() {
        return 'test123';
    }
```

I expected it to be:

```
test123
```

Comment: `form_fields[0].value()`...!? It *is* a function, you need to execute it to get the value.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to code! that saved me.

Comment: Perhaps part of your confusion stems from the name `value` that you have chosen. It is not a value, it is a method which when run will give you a value. Try naming it `getValue` and your mind will start thinking in terms of executing the method to get a value, rather than using a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_fields[0].value` *is* a function, not the return value from it.  You need to call the function:

```
console.log(form_fields[0].value());
```